# ¿Cómo consigo dibujar una linea a partir de varios puntos en JAVA?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Tengo este código que genera varios puntos para formar una linea, pero conforme la linea se va haciendo mas vertical los puntos se van separando y no queda un linea si no un montón de puntos, ¿cómo lo soluciono?

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LineExample extends JPanel{

public LineExample() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
} // constructor

private void draw(Graphics g){
    // dibujar los ejes del plano cartesiano
    g.setColor(Color.red);    

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    linearFunction(g, 0, 0, 600, 600);
    linearFunction(g, 0, 0, 100, 600);

} // draw

// funcion lineal f(x) = m x + b
// x1 y x2 es el rango en el que se graficara la funcion
private void linearFunction(Graphics g, double x0, double y0, double x1, double y1){        

    double y;
    //double punto;

    //calculo de pendiente y del termino b (interseccion con eje y)
    double m = (y0 - y1) / (x0 - x1);
    double b = y0 - ((y0 - y1) / (x0 - x1)) * x0;

    for(double x = x0; x <= x1; x += 1){
    //for(double x = x0; x <= x1; x += 0.1){
         y = (m * x + b);// * 10; // se multiplica por 10 para escalar el punto a representar en pantalla
         //punto = x;// * 10;
         g.drawLine((int)coord_x(x), (int)coord_y(y), (int)coord_x(x), (int)coord_y(y)); 
    } // for

}// linearFunction


private double coord_x(double x)
{
    return x;
}

private double coord_y(double y)
{
    double real_y = (double)this.getHeight() - y;
    return real_y;
}   


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // se llama al meto draw
    draw(g);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Graphing Function");
    window.setContentPane(new LineExample());
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    window.pack();
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocation(150, 100);
    window.setVisible(true);         
}

} // fin clase
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses el [algoritmo de Bresenham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Bresenham). Aqui esta el pseudo código:

```
Funcion LineaBresenham( X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
      // 0 - Distancias que se desplazan en cada eje
      dY = (Y2 - Y1)
      dX = (X2 - X1)

      // 1 - Incrementos para las secciones con avance inclinado
      Si (dY >= 0) luego
          IncYi = 1
      Sino
          dY = -dY
          IncYi = -1
      Fin si

      Si (dX >= 0) luego
          IncXi = 1
      Sino
          dX = -dX
          IncXi = -1
      Fin si

      // 2 - Incrementos para las secciones con avance recto:
      Si (dX >= dY) luego
          IncYr = 0
          IncXr = IncXi
      Sino
          IncXr = 0
          IncYr = IncYi

          // Cuando dy es mayor que dx, se intercambian, para reutilizar el mismo bucle.
          // ver octantes blancos en la imagen encima del código
          k = dX: dX = dY: dY = k
      Fin si

      // 3  - Inicializar valores (y de error).
      X = X1: Y = Y1
      avR = (2 * dY)
      av = (avR - dX)
      avI = (av - dX)

      // 4  - Bucle para el trazado de las línea.
      Hacer
          DibujarPixel(X, Y, Color) // Como mínimo se dibujará siempre 1 píxel (punto).
          Mensaje(av + " ") // (debug) para ver los valores de error global que van apareciendo.
          Si (av >= 0) luego
              X = (X + IncXi)     // X aumenta en inclinado.
              Y = (Y + IncYi)     // Y aumenta en inclinado.
              av = (av + avI)     // Avance Inclinado
          Sino
              X = (X + IncXr)     // X aumenta en recto.
              Y = (Y + IncYr)     // Y aumenta en recto.
              av = (av + avR)     // Avance Recto
          Fin si
      Repetir hasta que (X = X2) // NOTA: La condición de 'Repetir Hasta', se debe cambiar si se elige 'Repetir Mientras'
   Fin funcion
```